# How to code a php multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im having trouble trying to code this in PHP:

```
{
   "value": {
          "board": [
                  {"name": "Abdul-Jabbar", "values": [38387, 1560, 24.6]},
                  {"name": "Karl Malone", "values": [36928, 1476, 25.0]},
                  {"name": "Michael Jordan", "values": [32292, 1072, 30.1]},
                  {"name": "W. Chamberlain", "values": [31419, 1045, 30.1]},
                  {"name": "Kobe Bryant", "values": [29484, 1161, 25.4]},
                  {"name": "Shaq O Neal", "values": [28596, 1207, 23.7]},
                  {"name": "Moses Malone", "values": [27409, 1329, 20.6]},
                  {"name": "Elvis Hayes", "values": [28313, 1303, 21.0]},
                  {"name": "H. Olajuwon", "values": [26946, 1238, 21.8]}
                  ]
            }
}
```

So far I have this:

```
  $cart = array();

  foreach ($deliveries as $delivery) {

    // get name of the message sent.
    $msgFilter = array('id' => $delivery->messageId);
    $message = array_pop($client->readMessages(array('pageNumber' => 1,
                             'includeContent' => false,
                             'filter' => $msgFilter))->return);



   $cart[] = array(
    "value" => array(
        array(
            "message" => $message->name
        ),
        array(
            "value" => $delivery->revenue
        )
    )
  );


  }

  $postData = json_encode($cart);
```

I cant figure out how to wrap value and board around the array?!?

Comment: The php json_decode function might help...

Comment: Refer this - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is kinda confusing to me
the to-be-made array is actually an object/array mixture in sense of json
a better represention would be

value.board.array_part

if you just want to wrap the cart array with board and value arrays

```
$board = array("board"=>$cart);
$val = array("value"=> $board);
```

Comment: Thank you - Im actually quite confused too, thats why I posted on here!